# MediaPlayer reset() method not working

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a listView which consists of songlist. on clicking on each item, a new intent is fired up which loads another activity which plays the song.

```
//code used in listItemListener

    int songIndex = position;
    Intent n = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NowPlaying.class);
    n.putExtra("SongIndex", songIndex);
    startActivity(n);
```

Here NowPlaying class plays the song. But the problem is
when one song is currently being played, and i chose another song from the list, another song also starts to play without the first one being stopped. how can i prevent that? I tried using reset() method but its not working.

Here is the code from NowPlaying class.

```
//code portion of onCreate method
//other necessary things already initialized here

 Intent intent = getIntent();
 int songIndex = intent.getIntExtra("SongIndex", 0);

 currentSongId = songIndex;
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

initMusic();
```

initMusic() sets other values for layout, sets playerStatus variable to true and calls playMusic();

```
 public void playMusic(String path) {

    if (playerStatus == true) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        //
    }
}
```

Here is the adapter code

```
//other method overhere
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
            holder.t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listSubtitle);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.t1.setText(list.get(position).get(0));
        holder.t2.setText(list.get(position).get(2));

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView t1;
        TextView t2;

    }
```

Everything is working as usual, song is being played but the problem is they are being overlapped. whenever i chose another song to play from the list, it gets overlapped and plays along with previous one. Is is due to separate activity which is being created for each song?

Comment: we need the code of your adapter also

Comment: Long story short - You SHOULD NOT start a new `Activity` every time you want to play an audio track. You SHOULD keep a single `MediaPlayer` in a `Service` and use that one instance to play audio.

Comment: @Dave what about making mediaPlayer static and using that same instance again and again?

Comment: @darkknight That is a possibility. Static instances can become troublesome sometimes (maybe you need to worry about concurrent access?), and I personally prefer the `Service` approach (it's more modular and testable). But a static `MediaPlayer` will probably get you moving.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in my mp3 playing app, was to reuse the same `mediaPlayer` and get a Player from the `mediaPlayer`, then `stop()` the Player and `close()` the Player.  Something like this:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(datasource);
mediaPlayer.setPlaybackLoop(false);
player = mediaPlayer.getPlayer();
player.start():

...

// you may need 
// player.stop():
player.close();
```